# Relationship of Mithra and Varuna

Tags: hindu, interpretation, translation, persian

Just need an answer about the two gods [Mithra and Varuna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitra%E2%80%93Varuna), their situation actually.

I know that Mithra isn't worshiped at all, but I read and suspect personally that his name still remains in the "Indian subconscious", where it seems that he became a simple word related to friendship or something else like that (Mithram or Mithran?). So a confirmation of this survivalism is hoped.

For Varuna, I just want to learn more about him, if he was related to Justice, I remember that his worship is limited today, and that he is primarily associated with Water, Rivers, Sea... But I want also to know if he was associated with the Night, maybe he was the dichotomy of Mithra, that I associate with the Sun and the Light.

I'm focused particularly to these two gods, because I've read that a French anthropologist considered them as a "couple", Mithra associated with the notion of "Agreement" (*Contrat* in French) and Varuna with the "Oath" (*Serment* in French). This idea sounds a bit true for me, because with the little knowledge that I have in this subject, Mithra appeared to me as a god "Friend of the Human kind". Varuna, like I knew about him (a kind of poem/song which stant like a praise or more a complain about his cruelty, notably for the floods), appears as a terrifiant god.

All these questions for a student of secondary for his homework of Philosophy about Justice.

*Sorry for my bad English (made with the help of Google Translate) and please only answers which are academically correct.*

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: There are contributors on this forum that know a great deal more about Mithraism than I, and have made the point that it influences the Christian conception of absolute good and evil.  My understanding is that the nemesis is [Ahriman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angra_Mainyu), which is equivalent to the [Ahura Mazda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahura_Mazda)/Angra Mainyu dichotomy.  I'm not qualified to write in much detail about Mitra–Varuna, but I will be quite interested in the formal answers.  Welcome to Mythology!

Comment: *Mitra-Varuna* is a classic book by Georges Dumezil (easily found online). Please note that the Indian name is written Mitra while Mithra is the persian (the latin is Mithras); there is a recent book "Images of Mithra" (Oxf. 2017) which gives a broad perspective and provides a wealth of historical material (e.g. about Miiro in Bactria, Mihr in Iran).

Comment: [Full text of "Georges Dumézil Mitra Varuna An Essay On Two Indo European Representations Of Sovereignty (1990)](https://archive.org/stream/GeorgesDumzilMitraVarunaAnEssayOnTwoIndoEuropeanRepresentationsOfSovereigntyZoneBooks1990/Georges%20Dum%C3%A9zil-Mitra-Varuna_%20An%20Essay%20on%20Two%20Indo-European%20Representations%20of%20Sovereignty-Zone%20Books%20%281990%29_djvu.txt)  But I'd still love to see some formal answers here on Stack!

Comment: "*Mithra isn't worshiped at all*" Really? Consider some attributes of the religion:  
— icons feature him sitting at a feast
— catechism mentions "linen", "wrapped", "savior", "drink and food", …
— ceremonies involve a cup and bread
— temples were enclosed for private ceremonies (other religions used public displays)
— initiates made their way through grades, up to "Father"
— "Fathers" wore mitres, elaborate jeweled robes, and a ring
— he was born in a cave, on December 25