# Persian Zeus in Xenophon's Cyropaedia

Tags: comparative, zeus, persian

In the [*Cyropaedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyropaedia), the fictional biography of Cyrus the Great, there are, at least, 26 instances of ["Zeus"](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/searchresults?documents=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0204&language=en&inContent=true&all_words=zeus&any_words=&bad_words=#), in many cases used like... "By Zeus!"

This is [*interpretatio graeca*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretatio_graeca), of course, but, if we reverse the process, who would be that god of the Achaemenids that in Xenophon's work gets called "Zeus"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer in the book [*Xenophon's Cyropaedia: Style, Genre, and Literary Technique*](https://books.google.es/books?id=uqTIHmg4LsoC&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=persian+zeus+cyropaedia+%22ahura+mazda%22&source=bl&ots=YT4HGZl-id&sig=VkuNhoTnlTPjdu4IBqE9E4Rq6RE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwirp7nY8v3aAhXF0xQKHehTAUQQ6AEwCHoECAAQTQ#v=onepage&q=persian%20zeus%20cyropaedia%20%22ahura%20mazda%22&f=false), by Professor Deborah Levine Gera:

> The gods Cyrus sacrifices to are all Greek ones, although Xenophon may
>   have had their Persian counterparts in mind: Zeus is actually meant to
>   be Ahura Mazda, Hestia is the god of the hearth-fire, Helios is
>   Mithra, etc.

In [*Traditions of the Magi: Zoroastrianism in Greek and Latin Literature*](https://books.google.es/books?id=cNUEnHU0BPoC&pg=PA259&lpg=PA259&dq=persian+zeus+%22ahura+mazda%22&source=bl&ots=ZIJGl_ThD-&sig=t9vB3Rya3KPEDEZj7PtR7mYyCVI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjHltvj9v3aAhWEVRQKHTpKAuIQ6AEwCHoECAAQTw#v=onepage&q=persian%20zeus%20%22ahura%20mazda%22&f=false), by Dr. Albert F. de Jong the question is more thoroughly addressed:

> *Ahura Mazda = Zeus*
>
> The identification of Ahura Mazda with Zeus is more frequently
>   encountered in Greek literature than the Iranian name of the divinity.
>   It is commonly accepted that it is always Ahura Mazda who is to be
>   understood when Greek authors mention Zeus among the Persians.

As an example, the same Persian Zeus can be found earlier in Herodotus' *Histories*:

> As to the customs of the Persians, I know them to be these. It is not
>   their custom to make and set up statues and temples and altars, but
>   those who do such things they think foolish, because, I suppose, they
>   have never believed the gods to be like men, as the Greeks do; but
>   they call the whole circuit of heaven Zeus, and to him they sacrifice
>   on the highest peaks of the mountains; they sacrifice also to the sun
>   and moon and earth and fire and water and winds.

[Hdt. 1.131](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Hdt.+1.131&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0126)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and links!  (Can't access the de Jong text, but still quite a useful citation.)  This question could use your expertise: https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/4848/relationship-of-mithra-and-varuna

Comment: @Gibet You're right. Wikipedia article on [Cyrus the Great](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrus_the_Great#Religion_and_philosophy) even states this: "Though it is generally believed that Zarathushtra's teachings maintained influence on Cyrus' acts and policies, so far no clear evidence has been found to indicate that Cyrus practiced a specific religion. Pierre Briant wrote that given the poor information we have, 'it seems quite reckless to try to reconstruct what the religion of Cyrus might have been.'"